# Short story or novel about a battle of wits between humans and aliens aboard a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space

A short story or novel, from the '80s or earlier. It took place on a spaceship. If I recall correctly, the aliens resembled big cats and were evil and more intelligent than humans. The human protagonist had to find a clever solution to avoid getting killed or some such.

Comment: Feels like something from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Kzin_Wars

Comment: Do you remember any details about what the battle of wits entailed? Deception? Guerilla warfare? Seduction?

Comment: Is it not one of the tales from Voyage of the Space Beagle?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots "Big cats" suggests Kzin to me too, but I'm not sure about the "more intelligent" part.  Scream and leap! :)

Comment: I'm not sure, the battle of wits was about outthinking the opponent under time pressure, maybe something about a code

Comment: @DannyMcG I'd guess you're thinking of _Black Destroyer_ with the cat being _Coeurl_. I guess it's possible though it doesn't seem a great fit.

Comment: I've looked into Space Beagle and Kzin, and it's probably not one of those.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong about the cat resemblance, but I'm pretty sure they were smarter than humans

Comment: If not for the cat thing, it sound a lot like Fred Saberhagen's first *Berserker* story "Without a Thought" (a.k.a. "Fortress Ship"). However, in this story, the enemy is a robot spaceship.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berserker_(novel_series)